# iOS 9 how to invoke "Back to" feature programmatically

Tags: ios, ios9

Is there an api to invoke "Back to" action programmatically in order to return to the app which called (openurl) mine?

Comment: There's no way for an app to know which app (if any) opened it.

Comment: iOS 9 knows that an app was opened by other app. There is "Back to ..." button in upper left corner. May be there is a way to access it.

Comment: The OS knows a lot of things that it doesn't let your app know about or deal with.

Comment: Assuming that API existed, where would you put the code to call it? By definition your app is no longer running in the foreground, so you can't count on getting time, and even if your app does get some time it has no way of knowing if the other app is still the foreground app or if the user switched to some other app.

Comment: The current app wants to call to previous app bypassing the openurl mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible for you to redirect back to the app

The reason is

The only possible way for launching another app programmatically(Exposed by Apple) is via URLScheme. That means the current app should know the URL scheme of the to-be-launched app.
In your case the launched app does not not know the URL scheme of the launched app. So there is no way to go back to the previous app.